# THREE.js - ExtrudeGeometry at a slant

Tags: three.js, 3d, geometry

In THREE.js, is there a way to use `ExtrudeGeometry()` in a way that the extrude depth rises as a slant. For instance, say I draw an Odd Shape:

[shape design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6suXY.png)

and I extrude it upward into a mesh. Instead of a flat top, however, I want it to rise with a slant like this.

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ubA.png)

(p.s. I used Blender to create the example images.)

I'm using the following method.

```
const shape = new THREE.Shape()
   .moveTo(0,0)
   .lineTo(1, 0.5)
   .lineTo(2, 1)
   ...
   .lineTo(0, 0);

const extrudeSettings = {
   steps:16,
   depth:10, // <-- Right here is where my question is: can this be adjusted to an angle of some kind?
   bevelEnabled: false
}

const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF});
const mesh     = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Is there anything I can do to produce the effect I was wanting in slanting the top at a defined angle? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the Blender image again. All of the extruded vertices are vertical from their origin point, they just _follow_ an angle with their height. So instead of trying to apply an angle here, just extrude to a depth of 1, then use math to adjust the height value of each of the vertices to match where they should be when following the slope.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a boolean operation using constructive solid geometry (CSG) with the package `three-js-csg`.

```
npm i --save three-js-csg
```

Create an object that will cut away at the original geometry at whatever angle I need.